# Why does my Android Application crash after I add a listView to it?

Tags: android

It ran correctly before I added some new code into the program. I wanted to add a listView to show some message, but it doesn't work. When the App gets into this activity, the program crashes...
I added :

```
    String[] studentList = {"zhangsan","lisi"};
    ListView stdListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,studentList);
    stdListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    stdListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String result = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            AlertDialog.Builder choice = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditActivity.this);
            choice.setTitle(result);
        }
    });
```

to:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    String[] studentList = {"zhangsan","lisi"};
    ListView stdListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.studentListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,studentList);
    stdListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    stdListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String result = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            AlertDialog.Builder choice = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditActivity.this);
            choice.setTitle(result);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

And the following is the xml file of layout.
And I added:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/studentListView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="n402lab.door.EditActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_edit">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/studentListView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide your Error message and StackTrace!

Comment: try removing these lines: `NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);` and `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: Please add your logcat

Comment: Thanks very much. I debug the program and found the problem myself!

Answer (score 0):

After I saw the comment on this question, I tried to debug it myself. Before that I didn't know how to debug a application.
I saw "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView"
And I search for solution and finally I replace "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2"
by "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"
and it works.! Thanks very much!

Comment: great answer thnk u i iwll use it